# Multithreaded FTP upload. Is it possible?

Tags: php, python, ftp, curl, multithreading

I need to upload multiple files from directory to the server via FTP and SFTP.
I've solved this task for SFTP with python, paramiko and threading. But I have problem with doing it for FTP. I tried to use ftplib for python, but it seems that it doesn't support threading and I upload all files one by one, which is very slow.

I'm wondering is it even possible to do multithreading uploads with FTP protocol without creating separate connections/authorizations (it takes too long)?

Solution can be on Python or PHP. Maybe CURL? Would be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

There is an effor of creating an [asynchronous FTP client](http://effbot.org/zone/asyncore-ftp-client.htm) but basically the FTP protocol allows synchronous commands. To allow parallel downloads/uploads you need to open multiple FTP connections. This can be done by ftplib and threads.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to concurrency besides through is asynchronous io. For Python the standard toolkit for asynchronous network is [Twisted](http://www.twistedmatrix.com).

Take a look at this FTP client [example](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/examples/ftpclient.py) in Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something might be possible with the pycurl module.

There are two examples that if you put them together would work.

Go here: http://pycurl.cvs.sourceforge.net/pycurl/pycurl/examples/

and look into the retriever-multi.py and file_upload.py for examples on how to possibly put them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script in multiple command prompts / shells (just make sure each file is only handled once by all the different scripts). I am not sure if this quick and dirty trick will improve transfer speed though..